# merging list of tables without changing the orders of labels

Tags: r

i am trying to merge list of table by the first column but the order are getting changed and I want order of rows should be same as per first iteration.

```
so the output of my first function is list of dataframes

df_list1 <- data.frame(c= c("tml 14","tml 26","tml 73","tml 24","tml 95","tml 60","tml 77","tml 8","tml 19"),
                  "CAD"=c(399,590,287,353,483,591,184,501,590))
df_list2 <- data.frame(c= c("tml 14","tml 26","tml 73","tml 24","tml 95","tml 60","tml 77","tml 8","tml 19"),
                  "NHA"=c(556,188,446,583,398,505,461,737,164))
df_list3 <- data.frame(c= c("tml 14","tml 26","tml 73","tml 24","tml 95","tml 60","tml 77","tml 8","tml 19"),
                  "BHS"=c(356,337,712,255,573,598,622,144,159))
df_list4 <- data.frame(c= c("tml 14","tml 26","tml 73","tml 24","tml 95","tml 60","tml 77","tml 8","tml 19"),
                  "KLI"=c(686,630,627,498,551,159,253,448,437))

my function1 is like 


function1 <- df_list2[[i]]<- function(df,var,rownames[i]) 
df_list[i]<- do.call(rbind,df_list2)

now df is the output list like df1 , df2, df3.......

and I want to join those list of data frames to create one table
and I am trying like below

tbl<-Reduce(function(...)merge(...,all=TRUE,by="C"),df_list)
```

do we have any solution where i can keep the same order of rows...??

output be like

[image]

Comment: created the required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `full_join` with `reduce` which will give the output in the same order

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
reduce(mget(str_c('df_list', 1:4)), full_join, by = 'c')
```

Comment: looking to make it dynamic because df_list can be many .......n

Comment: why we are using here 1:4...??